# Subtracting One Year

Tags: sql, date, dateadd

SELECT

```
@begindate = dateadd(mm,-1,CAST(datepart(mm,getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/15/' +                  CAST(datepart(YYYY,getdate() -1) AS varchar(4))),

@enddate = CAST(datepart(mm,getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/14/' + CAST(datepart(YYYY,getdate() -1) AS varchar(4))
```

Right now this code returns the dates May 15th - June 14th.  Those are the required dates that I need, but what I also need is for it to be in the year 2013, and this returns the year 2014.  I've tried doing a dateadd(yyyy, -1) and it didn't work.  So I was wondering if anyone knew how I would be able to get last years date.

Comment: Why didn't `dateadd(yyyy, -1, xxx)` work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? All this splitting, casting and concatenating (in the US format, definitely non-standard) obscures what you are asking

Comment: Get data from the 15th of the previous month to the 14th of the current month based on last year

Comment: Your current code returns two strings that can't be used for date comparisons unless the server/database/column collations are just right. If you used the two variables in a `WHERE` statement and got no results, that's probably the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DateAdd didn't work, there must have been an error in your implementation.   Try it like this after your existing code:

```
SET @begindate = dateadd(year, -1, @begindate);
SET @enddate = dateadd(year, -1, @enddate)
```

Comment: `@begindate` and `@enddate` are strings. Doing any kind of date arithmetic will convert them to dates using the server's format (most likely not the US format for anyone outside the US) with unexpected results

Comment: I did assume that the variables are datetime.  The user doesn't specify, and although his code builds a string, it's a string that can be implicitly converted to a date and used to populate a datetime variable.   There are many different ways to achieve his desired results, but I focused on the attempt to use dateadd() which didn't work.

Comment: The format used won't work in non-US locales so you can't assume that an implicit conversion is possible.

Answer (score 0):

declare @begindate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @begindate = dateadd(mm,-1,CAST(datepart(mm,getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/15/' + CAST(datepart(YYYY, getdate()) -  1 AS varchar(4)))

set @enddate = CAST(datepart(mm,getdate() ) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/14/' + CAST(datepart(YYYY, getdate()) -  1 AS varchar(4))

select @begindate
union all
select @enddate

Comment: This is what I thought too, but it says incorrect syntax near AS and I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: Works fine for me on SQLServer. What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with strings you can use date variables and date arithmetic:

```
declare @lastyear date=dateadd(yy,-1,cast(getdate() as date))
declare @currentMonth date=dateadd(d,-day(@lastyear),@lastyear)
declare @prevMonth date=dateadd(m,-1,@currentMonth)

select @lastyear,DATEADD(d,14,@currentMonth),DATEADD(d,15,@prevMonth)
```

In SQL Server 2012 it's even easier because you can use the [DATEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function to construct a new date from its parts.